# Can you reference a class inside of itself in Python?

Tags: python, class, recursion

If I have classes A and B, I basically want to do something like this:

```
class A:
    myDict = {A: 3, B: 2}
```

Since my reference isn't in a function, the class hasn't fully loaded by the time I try to use it.  How can I get around this?

Comment: You can't do this. Perhaps some example of why you want to would help us advise you on a solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The proper solution is to *move the dict outside the class*

```
class A:
    pass

A.mydict = {A: 3, B: 2}
```

which will result in exactly the values you would get if you could do what you ask for.

Comment: Or initialize the dict to {} in the class, and set it later, from outside.